# When I compile and install CARLA on Windows, I get the following error when running make PythonAPI:

Tags: windows, compilation, carla

```
-[Setup]: Installing Xercesc...
    -[install_xercesc]: [Batch params]: --build-dir "D:\AA\Epic Games\UnrealEngine\carla\Build\"
    -[install_xercesc]: A xerces installation already exists.
    -[install_xercesc]: Delete "D:\AA\Epic Games\UnrealEngine\carla\Build\xerces-c-3.2.3-install\" if you want to force a rebuild.
    -[install_xercesc]: Exiting...
系统找不到指定的文件。
-[Setup]: Installing Sqlite3
    -[install_sqlite3]: [Batch params]: --build-dir "D:\AA\Epic Games\UnrealEngine\carla\Build\"
    -[install_sqlite3]: Retrieving sqlite-amalgamation-3340100.
    -[install_sqlite3]: Extracting Sqlite3 from "sqlite-amalgamation-3340100.zip".
命令语法不正确。
系统找不到指定的路径。
用于 x64 的 Microsoft (R) C/C++ 优化编译器 19.29.30151 版
版权所有(C) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。

sqlite3.c
shell.c
c1: fatal error C1083: 无法打开源文件: “shell.c”: No such file or directory
c1: fatal error C1083: 无法打开源文件: “sqlite3.c”: No such file or directory
用于 x64 的 Microsoft (R) C/C++ 优化编译器 19.29.30151 版
版权所有(C) Microsoft Corporation。保留所有权利。

sqlite3.c
c1: fatal error C1083: 无法打开源文件: “sqlite3.c”: No such file or directory
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.29.30151.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: 无法打开输入文件“sqlite3.obj”
子目录或文件 D:\AA\Epic 已经存在。
处理: D:\AA\Epic 时出错。
子目录或文件 D:\AA\Epic 已经存在。
处理: D:\AA\Epic 时出错。
命令语法不正确。
命令语法不正确。
命令语法不正确。
D:\AA\Epic\*, 是否确认(Y/N)?
^C终止批处理操作吗(Y/N)? y
make: *** [setup] 错误 255
```

But in the file, there are two files shell.c and sqlite3.c.And the sqlite3.obj file does not exist.How to solve this problem?

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK in VS2019, but it didn't work.